# Hawking Temperature for a hairy BTZ Black Hole

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, ads-cft, holographic-principle

The metric of a hairy Black Hole is given by:
$$ds^2 = \frac{L^2}{z^2}\biggl(-g(z) dt^2 + \frac{e^{2 A(z)}}{g(z)} dz^2 +d\varphi^2\biggr), $$
where $L$ is the AdS length taken to be $1$,$A(z)$ is the form factor, and $z=\frac{1}{r}$, I wish to find the Hawking Temperature as a function of $r_h$ which is the horizon radius. Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Comment: I encountered such a calculation at a recent paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.00058 page 9.